# Restore overwritten files

Tags: lumia, storage, pictures, recovery

I wanted to copy some files from PC to MS Lumia 532 (internal storage - no ssd card) by mtp package (ubuntu). So I have used the mtp-connect with --sendfile flag and instead of sending file to /Pictures/Camera Roll directory it overwrote this directory to mkv file (which I wanted to copy here), so instead of having "Camera Roll" directory with pictures I have an mkv file with the name of Camera Roll... Is there any chances to restore Camera Roll directory ?

There was not OneDrive options enabled.

Comment: Have you been using your phone since or did you turn it off? Restoring files from flash memories is not easy but there are some tools out there (don't be stupid and get viruses nor pay) but they're mostly successful with rotating HDD.

Comment: There are companies specializing in restoration of information from HDDs and flash drives but they might be expensive. 

To avoid this happening again, either setup cloud sync (OneDrive) or sync with your PC now and then.